# MATLAB input it not a double error

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

My file is not working and I have no idea why.
When I run y = test(A, x) after I delcare:

> > A = floor(rand(8,100));
> >
> > x = floor(rand(100,1));

I get Undefined function 'test' for input arguments of type 'double'.

```
function [ output_args ] = untitled2( ~ )
    function y = test(A, x)
    %This function computes the pro
    duct of matrix A by
    vector x row-wise
    % define m number of rows here to feed into for loop
    [ma,na] = size(A);
    [mx,nx] = size(x);
    % use if statement to check for proper dimensions
    if(na == mx && nx == 1)
    y = zeros(ma,1);   % initialize y vector for n = 1:ma
    y(n) = A(n,:)*x;
    %end
    else
    disp('Dimensions of matrices do not match')
    y = [];
    end
    end
    end
```

Comment: You can't call nested function from the command window, only top-level functions.

Comment: So, how can I fix this? I'm new to this type of language

Answer (score 3):

As Ben Voigt correctly told you in comment your problem is that *test* is defined inside *untitled2*.

For the code you posted there's no need in doing such thing, so you can solve by just declaring test without the outer *untitled2*.  So just create a test.m file just use this part of code

```
function y = test(A, x)
    %This function computes the product of matrix A by vector x row-wise
    % define m number of rows here to feed into for loop
    [ma,na] = size(A);
    [mx,nx] = size(x);
    % use if statement to check for proper dimensions
    if(na == mx && nx == 1)
        y = zeros(ma,1);   % initialize y vector 
        for n = 1:ma
            y(n) = A(n,:)*x;
        end
    else
       disp('Dimensions of matrices do not match')
       y = [];
    end
end
```

And then call the function again

Comment: Ok, so I do this and it says line 4: not enough input line arguments.

Comment: One part of your code was inside a comment line. I've fixed it in the above shown code. Try to copy paste and do it again.

Comment: Ok, now when I run it, I get. Error in mfile (line 11)
y(n) = A(n,:)*x;

Comment: I've copy pasted the code above and it's working. So you probably made some error in the process I've above written, check carefully every step. In any case the problem you have now are not related to the question directly, if you still have problems even after another honest effort of trying to spot the error (again, it's working for me), consider opening another question.